# Python passing variable with multiple lines to payload

Tags: python, json

Below is the part of code I am trying to execute.

```
   msg="""line1 
line 2"""
    msg=f"\"{msg}\""
    payload="{\"Additional comments\" :"+msg+",\n  \"Short description\" : \"tests\",\n  \"Requester\" : \"test1\",\n  \"Impact\" : \"3\",\n  \"Contact type\" : \"test1 \"\n\n}\n"
```

My code throws this error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

But when I send a message as:

```
#without a new line \n, my code works fine
msg="Line one" # code works fine
```

Comment: First, your posted code obviously doesn't throw the error mentioned. But you're looking for `json.dumps`.

Comment: Consider using Python `json` module to encode values to JSON rather than trying to generate it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Put your data in a Python dictionary and use the `json` module to generate the text.  It will write valid JSON much more easily that trying to format it manually:

```py
import json

msg = '''line1
line2'''

data = {'Additional comments' : msg,
        'Short description' : 'tests',
        'Requester' : 'test1',
        'Impact' : '3',
        'Contact type' : 'test1'}

text = json.dumps(data,indent=2)
print(text)
```

Output:

```json
{
  "Additional comments": "line1\nline2",
  "Short description": "tests",
  "Requester": "test1",
  "Impact": "3",
  "Contact type": "test1"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. I made the changes. It works for me now